# kafka Consumer Upgrade to .9

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Hi I am working on kafka upgrade to .9 and also upgrading the kafka consumer to new java consumer released with .9. 
While upgrade, i am using the existing topics, Steps are just stoping the .8 kafka and Starting the .9 kafka pointing to same log.dirs, At consumer side, i am using the same group name and topic name,But the new consumer is consuming the messages again from starting position in the topic. I have committed them in .8. 
I am adding auto.offset.reset = earliest.

Any idea why it is happening or We need to first consume all the message with .8 consumer and let the lag to become 0.
Thanks
Sunny

Answer (score 0):

While 0.8 consumers store offsets in Zookeeper, 0.9 consumers store them in a specific Kafka topic. Consequently a 0.9 consumer will not normally see any offsets stored by a 0.8 consumer and as such will start consuming from start. There is a [FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-HowdowemigratetocommittingoffsetstoKafka%28ratherthanZookeeper%29in0.8.2?) that may help in migrating the offsets. To quote:

> 1) Upgrade your brokers and set dual.commit.enabled=false and offsets.storage=zookeeper (Commit offsets to Zookeeper Only).
>
> 2) Set dual.commit.enabled=true and offsets.storage=kafka and restart (Commit offsets to Zookeeper and Kafka).
>
> 3) Set dual.commit.enabled=false and offsets.storage=kafka and restart (Commit offsets to Kafka only).

(Have not tried this, just quoting.)

Comment: I tried to follow, but no luck :(  Do you see any other issue

Comment: "no luck" is not exactly a specific error description. Please update your question with what you did and what happened.

Comment: There is no error, the same thing happened as question. 
I have .8 consumer and 8.2.1 kafka,I am upgrading

Comment: There is no error, the same thing happened as question. Let me repeat my question.
I have .8 consumer and 8.2.1 kafka,I am upgrading it to .9 java consumer and .9 kafka , I verified 8.2.1 kafka was using zookeeper as "offset storage"
I followed the steps above, I updated the kafka to .9 pointing to same log dir that i had for .8 , then restarted the .8 consumer, 
it was consuming all the logs, regardless of offset Thanks

Comment: i applied the first point to one my consumer, it was consuming all the messages from topic, even though they were committed.

Comment: It would be better if you consume all the events beforehand and then upgrade whole kafka cluster to .9